# How to set group to a module automatically?

Tags: kernel-modules, group

I'm working on an embedded system with linux 4.19.

I have written a custom driver in a module `MyDriver.ko`. At startup, the module is automatically probed by the devicetree and it appears in `/dev`.

```
# ls -l /dev/mydriver 
crw-rw----    1 root     root      246,   0 May  5 08:23 /dev/mydriver
```

I'd like to set this driver's group automatically at startup :

```
# ls -l /dev/mydriver 
crw-rw----    1 root     MyGroup      246,   0 May  5 08:23 /dev/mydriver
```

How can I set the module's group automatically ?

Comment: You want to do that from within the module, or are you open for other solutions?

Comment: I'd like to avoid some startupscript with "chown" if it is reasonable... I'm open to other solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with udev. You just have to put a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with the appropriate content like

```
KERNEL=="mydriver", OWNER="username", GROUP="groupname", MODE="0640"
```